# .htaccess: Allowing cloud access (NODE.js) to my MediaWiki

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, heroku

Happy Monday!
I have a MediaWiki installation with the VisualEditor extension that works perfectly with the following .htaccess. The wiki is to be accessible ONLY to my employers companies and is on a shared host (Siteground).

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.triadfastener.com
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from [my company IP addresses, separated by spaces]
```

VisualEditor extension requires NODE.js, for which I am using Heroku. Doing a WHOIS on my Heroku Parsoid app returns a TON of different IP address (but all share the same Canonical Name: canonical.herokuapp.com). VisualEditor DOES NOT work with the above .htaccess in place (I'm assuming because access to the NODE.js (herokuapp.com) is blocked. I need to allow access to the herokuapp.com with my .htaccess

This does NOT work:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.triadfastener.com
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from herokuapp.com [my company IP addresses, separated by spaces]
```

Is there any way to allow NODE.js access through my Parsoid app on herokuapp.com using the .htaccess in the MediaWiki folder??? Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the Proximo Heroku add-on.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo) Basically it makes your app traffic come from a static IP. Seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I discovered that yesterday and installed it. I also determined my Heroku app's static IP and added it to the ALLOWED list (which is now 4 IP addresses, separated only by spaces). However, I still get the 500 error as the VisualEditor extension attempts to load. I'm afraid this may be because the Promixo add-on says that it is for "routing OUTBOUND traffic from your app through a static IP address". In my case, I think that the VisualEditor extension of my MediaWiki (on SiteGround) is making an INBOUND request, so is not allowed by Heroku.

Comment: (Pinging my static Heroku/Proximo IP address results in Request Timed Out). If I try a tracert to my Proximo IP address, I get "tracing route to ec1-my-static-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com". Interesting. (The traceroute gets to a point where the Requests Time Out.)